# Formulating a select query

Tags: sql

I'm having difficulty querying the following;

tablename = Account

**NAME | AccountCode | ParentAccountCode**

**John |    A1       |       NULL**

**Filip |    A2       |       A1**

I want a single query to select 2 columns

> first column = Name 
>   second column = ParentAccountName (custom)

The ParentAccountName column is filled with the Name that represent it's code.

So Filip has a ParentAccountCode A1, which is John, so the value in custom column ParentAccountName should be 'John'

It should be something like

I get it this way:

```
> SELECT A.Name, AA.Name AS ParentAccountName FROM Account AS A
>     INNER JOIN Account AS AA
>     ON A.ParentAccountNumber = AA.AccountNumber WHERE A.AccountNumber = 'A2'
```

Which results in ParentAccountName = John. 
So this is good, but when select where AccountNumber = A1, it doesn't show me the results.

How can I make SQL give me a resultset even if ParentAccountName = null?

Answer (score 1):

You need a left outer join instead of an inner join.

```
SELECT A.Name, AA.Name AS ParentAccountName FROM Account AS A
LEFT OUTER JOIN Account AS AA
ON A.ParentAccountNumber = AA.AccountNumber
```

Comment: Yup! This did the trick! 
Thanks a lot mscoon and sorry for my noobness... :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to do a self-join:

```
SELECT T1.Name, T2.Name AS ParentAccountName
FROM Account T1 INNER JOIN Account T2 ON (T2.Account = T1.ParentAccountCode)
```